# glUseProgram not loading shader in model

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, rendering

I have a code structure that has a Render with the rendering loop, a Shader class and a Model class. I am able to get my shaders to work when I implement them in the renderer, but I'm looking to assign them to a model and call render(), however I'm having an odd issue, that the shader works outside of the model, but not inside.

Shader structure:

```
class Shader
{
public:
unsigned int ID;

// constructor generates the shader on the fly
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr)
{
... Generate shaders...

//Assign program ID to the public unsigned int
ID = glCreateProgram();

...attach shaders to program and link...

}

//Install program for use in rendering
void use()
{
    glUseProgram(ID);
}
}
```

Model Structure:

```
class TextureModel
{
public:
    TextureModel(const std::string modelPath, const std::string texturePath)
{
...Initialize model, load in mesh,texture, create a VAO with vertex and
   index VBOs, set glAttribArray values...
}

Render(Shader* shader)
{
    //glUseProgram(4)    <---------- (3)

    shader->use();       <---------- (1)

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, IBO->GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
}
```

Renderer structure:

```
Shader* texShader;
TextureModel* Reindeer;

int main()
{
    texShader = new Shader("Shaders/camera.vs", "Shaders/textured.fs", "Shaders/passThrough.gs");

    Reindeer = new TextureModel("Models/reindeer_v1/reindeer_v1.obj", 
                                "Models/reindeer_v1/reindeer_diffuse.jpg");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

     ...Update camera, project and model matrices. Update the shader uniforms...

    //texShader->use()   <---------- (2)

    Reindeer->Render(texShader);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

The above code does not render my object.

At point (1) my model calls the texShader->use() passed in by TextureModel::Render(Shader*). For some reason this does not work, however if I call texShader->use() from the rendering loop it works, this is at point (2).

Also in debugging I found that the program ID assigned to texShader on creation is 4. If I put glUseProgram(4) in the model::Render(Shader*) block, this also works. Point (3).

Why does the glUseProgram() function work in all cases except when passed in to my model? I'm really confused at this one.

Comment: Did you verify whether `TexShader.ID` is still correct when you step into the `->use()`? This smells like memory corruption.

Comment: Yup it was the same. I figured out what the problem was. Turns out I had an issue with my geometry Shader (not in the above snippit) and this was blocking the values from being passed to the fragment shader. After sorting this out I managed to call it from the model.
I'm not too sure what I did to fix the issue... sorry. But its done now. If I find out concretely what happened I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've fixed it.

I've summarized my problem above, but in actual fact I am using two different shaders for different objects.

The both share the same vertex shader (using their own model matrices, with a camera uniform buffer object), use different fragment shaders, and share a geometry shader.

For some reason I am only able to have one instance of the geometry shader working at a time... I need to to further investigation.

Either way I've got the above issue solved.

Thanks